# how to create bestseller slider on magento

Tags: jquery, magento

I need to create best-seller in magento ....
I code some line..but its not working..

I need to know that what shout i modified in this code...
for bestseller....

```
 $todayDate  = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);

        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
        $collection->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds());

        $collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection)
            ->addStoreFilter()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('special_from_date', array('or'=> array(
                0 => array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayDate),
                1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
            ), 'left')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('special_to_date', array('or'=> array(
                0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $todayDate),
                1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
            ), 'left')
            ->addAttributeToFilter(
                array(
                    array('attribute' => 'special_from_date', 'is'=>new Zend_Db_Expr('not null')),
                    array('attribute' => 'special_to_date', 'is'=>new Zend_Db_Expr('not null'))
                    )
              )
            ->addAttributeToSort('special_from_date', 'desc')
            ->setPageSize($this->getProductsCount())
            ->setCurPage(1)
        ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the best sellers products this way:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/report_bestsellers_collection')
        ->setModel('catalog/product');
```

If you want them for a specific store view just add this line

```
$collection->addStoreFilter($storeId);
```

If you want a limit add:

```
$collection->setCurPage(1)->setPageSize($limit);
```